# Generating Excel from C# - How to make diagonal borders?

Tags: c#, xml, excel

I am using C# to generate an Excel spreadsheet and saving it in Excel 2003 XML format using [this library](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/excelxmllibrary.aspx). I need to make a cell that contains a big X. The sample sent by the client uses a left and right diagonal border to accomplish this.

I've have been unable to find the correct code syntax to set a cell's style in this manner. How is this done?

Here is how it is supposed to look:

[alt text http://preview.moveable.com/JM/ExcelBorders.gif](http://preview.moveable.com/JM/ExcelBorders.gif)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in XML saved from Excel it appears like this:

```
<Style ss:ID="s22">
   <Borders>
    <Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"/>
    <Border ss:Position="DiagonalLeft" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"/>
    ...
```

I don't know this library but I've seen that you can define cell's borders using `XmlStyle` class, specially setting the `Border.Sides` property:

```
XmlStyle sBorder = new XmlStyle();
sBorder.Border.Color = Color.Black;
sBorder.Border.Weight = 1;
sBorder.Border.LineStyle = Borderline.Continuous;
sBorder.Border.Sides = BorderSides.DiagonalLeft; //<-- here where I'm not sure!
                                                 //(I can't access the docs
                                                 // right now to check that Enum)

sheet[x, y].Style = sBorder;
```

thought may be this will help if you haven't tried.

Comment: That was my guess too, but it doesn't seem to be supported.

Comment: can't you modify the source code to support `DiagonalLeft` & `DiagonalRight` values? Seeing the XML, I don't see much of a difference comparing to `Left border`.